# Setting up redis with docker

Tags: authentication, redis, docker

I have setup a basic redis image based on the following instructions: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/running_redis_service/

With my snapshot I have also edited the redis.conf file with **requirepass**.

My server runs fine and I am able to access it remotely using redis-cli however the authentication isn't working.  I am wondering if the config file isn't being used but when I try starting the container with:

> docker run -d -p 6379:6379 jwarzech/redis /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf

the container immediately crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default config of redis is set to be a daemon. You can't run a daemon within a docker container, otherwise, lxc will lose track of it and will destroy the namespace.

I just tried doing this within the container:

```
$>redis-server - << EOF
requirepass foobared
EOF
```

Now, I can connect to it and I will get a 'ERR operation not permitted'. When I connect with `redis-cli -a foobared`, then it works fine.